# CRS or SRS in Web Map Service

Tags: javascript, leaflet, wms

I am implementing a Web Map Service Server based on specifications given at http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms

The document is telling me to use the request paramter CRS, but when i inspect http requests leaflet uses against my implementation it seems to use a SRS paramtere instead.

I would like to follow the specification. Is it configurable with leaflet to what version of the spec it should use. (assuming SRS is a old version).

Do WMS clients in general not follow the specifications?

```xml
<script type="text/javascript">

    var nexrad = new L.TileLayer.WMS("/wms", {
        layers: "image",
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
    });

    var map2 = new L.Map('map2', {
        center: new L.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 10,
        layers: [nexrad],
        maxZoom: 28,
        minZoom: 0,
        zoomControl: true
    });

</script>
```